# Equivalent of C strcpy in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a code in C,

```
struct sFoo
{
   char* name;
   char* fullname;
};

sFoo* foo = (sFoo*)malloc(sizeof(sFoo));
foo->name = (char*)malloc(10);

strcpy(foo->name, "HELLO");
```

What is the equivalent of strcpy in C++?

Comment: To copy a `string` into another `string`?  Or to copy `char*` into `char*`?  Or to copy `char*` into `string`?

Comment: Since `strcpy()` is provided by the C++ standard in namespace `std`, the immediate answer is: the equivalent of [`strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) in C++ is [`std::strcpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy). That said, the real question you should be asking is whether any of this is needed in C++ in the first place, and the answer is no. See [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: @nhgrif copy char* to a char*

Comment: @domlao The same as in C.  `ALMOST` anything that works in C will also work exactly the same way in C++.

Comment: +1 to @WhozCraig, and it's not actually necessary in C either. Use `strdup`. (And you can do that in C++ also.)

Comment: @nhgrif not everything; (automatic `void*` promotion to any pointer type without casting, for example, is a C-only feature).

Comment: @rici ..certainly, though it is not part of either standard. `strdup` is part of XOPEN/POSIX, nor is it helpful if you already have a target buffer, though it would fit in this OP's code.

Comment: @WhozCraig: And XOPEN/POSIX is what? Chopped liver? :) `strdup` is certainly, shall we say, widely available, possibly more so than some things which are in "a standard", like `strtok_s`. Clearly, `strcpy` is useful and important but I see a lot of code like OP's, much of which fails to get the allocation correct, for which `strdup` would really be a much better choice. In the interests of reducing the number of buffer overflow vulnerabilities in the world, I therefore use every possible opportunity to promote it.

Comment: @rici You'll be hard pressed to find a bigger fan of that function than I when I'm coding C, primarily because every conceivable platform  I target supports it. I make no qualms about its utility nor availability. My point was simply it isn't *required* per the standards. *Why* that is at this juncture I can only speculate. There aren't many functions I sincerely wish the standards committees would just add and be done with it. That is certainly one of them, especially since near-everyone (including myself) uses it anyway, but alas, such is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use std::string

```
int main()
{
    std::string myString = "Hello, there!";

    std::string myOtherString = myString;  //Makes a copy of myString


}
```

std::string is the standard C++ string type and it handles copy just like that for you!

Comment: Too bad, I have a legacy code that I can't change with char* member variable.

Comment: you can call myString.c_str() to get a char* back if that helps

Comment: But otherwise if you can't use std::string for compatibility reasons I suppose you can use strcpy

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use char* instead of std::string, the general purpose method from `<algorithm>` is `std::copy`.

```
char* hello = "HELLO";
std::copy(hello, hello + 6, foo->name);
```

Of course, `strlen(hello) + 1)` may be substituted for 6 if the contents of hello are determined dynamically.

At the end of the day, however, it is likely less error prone to simply use `strcpy`.

Comment: what make it less error prone? Given that we can use `strncpy`

Comment: @AdrianShum: [`strncpy()` is not a "safer" `strcpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: @AdrianShum `std::copy`, like `memcpy`, simply looks at memory and copies what you tell it to (potentially leading to overrunning your array). `strncpy` (which, yes, is a better choice than `strcpy`) is string-aware and will copy either until it finds a null terminator or until it hits your maximum limit (at which points it adds the terminator). Both, however, are unsafe in that it is assumed that the destination is sufficiently large to hold what you're trying to copy.

Comment: To add to @argiopeweb, the reason `strncpy` is unsafe is because it doesn't guarantee a NULL-terminated target. If `foo->name` is only, say, 3 bytes long, then `strncpy(foo->name, "HELLO", 3)` will copy `'H' 'E' 'L'` and leave off the `'\0'`. That means next time you use the string you'll likely overrun your buffer.

Comment: but what I don't get is, std::copy and memcpy is not doing anything better than strncpy in the sense of null termination: std::copy and memcpy is also not null terminating the target buffer either, which leave you a string that will "overrun the buffer next time you use"

Comment: @KeithThompson Honestly I don't agree on the quoted article: strncpy() is not totally safe but it is SAFER than strcpy().  It is at least safer in the case that, it allow you to provide number of char to copy so that it will not write beyond the allocated memory pointed by the target.  Yes, there are still lots of deficits in strncpy() but still, it is *safer* than strcpy()

Comment: @AdrianShum: The problem with `strncpy` is that makes it very easy to generate a destination array that doesn't contain a string. What good is it to avoid overwriting the end of the destination if the next operation you perform is likely to go past it anyway? `strcpy` doesn't have that problem, as long as you first verify that the destination array is big enough. If you want to do what `strncpy` probably *should* have done, you can write `dest[0] = '\0'; strncat(dest, src, n);`

Comment: strcnpy is not an equivalent to strcpy. strncpy has to be the worst designed function in the entire C API. Completely useless, especally as many programmers believe it's just a length limitted version of strcpy.

Comment: @KeithThompson well, I used to do `strncpy(src, target, targetLen -1); target[targetLen-1] = '\0';`, for which I don't see anything deficit compared with your case.

Comment: @john yes, probably it is bad but I cannot find using memcpy/std:copy anything better in such sense, as it still suffer from the problem of non-terminating string, as an inappropriate use of strncpy produce.  Did I missed something?

Comment: @AdrianShum If I had to copy C strings I would use strdup, as mentioned in the comments to the question. If I wanted to be entirely sure I was writing standard C++ I'd first write my own version of the strdup function. But most of all I would normally avoid C strings in the first place.

Comment: @john but aren't we discussing why std::copy/memcpy is preferred to strncpy?  It is same for me that, if I am writing C++, I would prefer using std::string instead of C style string, but that's not what we are discussing, right?  And, strdup is simply not equivalent to strcpy family/memcpy, as strdup is allocating memory from heap internally, while strcpy/memcpy is copying to a given buffer.

Comment: @AdrianShum As mentioned in my answer, I would not prefer `std::copy` or `memcpy` over `strcpy`. It is simply another option which domlao may want to consider. `std::copy` is not preferred because it is less safe for string handling than either `strncpy` or `strcpy`, as both the latter functions are C-string-aware. Several better options to `strcpy` have been mentioned in the above comments, but that does not change my assertion that all are safer than `std::copy` for string handling.

Comment: @argiopeweb thanks for the clarification, and that's precisely what I am asking: why std::copy is less error-prone if we compare it with strncpy().  Good to hear that we are on the same page that we all think it is not less error-prone  :)